# Get variable defined in service from another controller

Tags: php, symfony, service

I will go straight to the point

I have these 2 simple controllers:

```
/**
* @Route("/controller1", name="controller1")
*/
public function controller1(UserVerification $verification)
{
    $verification->setVerificationCode();

    return $this->render('user_settings/settings.html.twig');
}

/**
 * @Route("/controller2", name="controller2")
 */
public function controller2(UserVerification $verification)
{
    $verificationCode = $verification->getVerificationCode();

    return $this->render('user_settings/settings.html.twig', [
        'verificationCode' => $verificationCode
    ]);
}
```

And these two methods in my UserVerification Service:

```
public function setVerificationCode(){
    $this->verificationCode = rand(100000, 999999);
    return $this;
}

public function getVerificationCode(): int
{
    return $this->verificationCode;
}
```

My question is: Is that real to get verificationCode in controller2 which has been set in controller1? For now in that example above in controller1 when i use method getVerificationCode() it's successfully returning some random code, but of course in controller2 it's returning null. Is there a way to share service instance?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You have two separate requests for these controllers. You should persist data in database, session or somewhere else.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson if not defined otherwise - symfony container will return same instance of service. So, I presume OP just uses two requests and expects that data between'em will somehow be saved.

Comment: If you want to share data between two requests, you have to persist it somewhere like @u_mulder said.

Comment: what symfony version you are using ?

Comment: I'm using symfony 4

Answer (score 1):

Here is the point:

In Symfony , by default , services are shared , that mean the same instance is working for many request , if you want the contrary you can modify it in service declaration of your service like  :

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\SomeNonSharedService:
        shared: false
        # ...
```

But , here , it's different , you function is returning  a random value , so even you are using the same service instance , it's sure that you will not have the same result , so here you can do 2 thing :

*1- save data into session in case this logic concerns user when is logged in :*

*2- save data into the dababase*

For the two solutions , you have for exmaple to verify if the value already exist into session/DB , like for the first this , it's your service that occur the result , and in the sametime store the value samewhere , so the next request , it will receive data from where you sotre it .

here is an example if you are using Session :

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Services\CodeService:
    arguments:
        - "@session"
```

ServiceCode :

```
<?php
namespace App\Services;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
class CodeService
{
    private $session;

    public function __construct( Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    pulic function setVerificationId(){ 
      if(isset(!$this->session->get('verificationCode'))){
       $this->session->set('verificationCode', rand(100000, 999999)); 
      }
      return this->getVerificationId();
    }
    public function getVerificationId()
    {
        return $this->session->get('verificationCode');
    }


}
```

> This case is working only if you are using session , if not , do the
>   same thing using EntityManager to store data somewhere in database.

Hope that help you.

Comment: Storing data in session is secure? I mean, in my case that code should not be possible to gain by unauthorized persons

Comment: exaclty , so if you want to store data into db , you can do it  with the same way just instead to inject Session , use EntityManager